# show only one category and filter by tag

Tags: posts, categories, filters, search, tags

I have a page that I would like to show one posts from just one specific category. I'd then like a function to search the posts within this one category on just this page. I don't mind how it's searchable tag or otherwise, but I want to only bring up seatch results from that one specific category.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This would help you to fetch a single post from a specific category.

```
$args = array('post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page'=> 1, 'cat' => get_cat_ID('Category Name'));
```